# Like Box Does Not Display - Using Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: dreamweaver, facebook-likebox

I am trying to add the Like Box to a web site but nothing displays.  I have tried both the HTML and the Iframe code with no success.  Any assistance is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; 
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);  
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/RockyMountainKoiClub" data-width="292" data-height="500" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

IFRAME:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FRockyMountainKoiClub&amp;width=292&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your page thru the linter tool at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and fix any errors it says there are.